# Which processor does a Macbook Pro 13" have?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm looking at buying a macbook pro for my development work while I'm travelling.

The advert states:
2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo Processor

But which one?  is it an E6600 or E4400 or something else.

I'm wanting to know if the processor they use has VT extensions enabled because I'm going to load Virtual Box and need to run 64bit windows ultimate and 64bit versions of linux virtualized.

EDIT:

I ended up buying the 2.66Ghz model which is a P8800.  It is 64bit and does have the VT extensions I needed.

Comment: Maybe call Apple. If they stymie you, at least they'll do it right™.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to laptop magazine it's a P8600, which according to intel's spec is a 64-bit CPU.

http://www.laptopmag.com/review/laptops/apple-macbook-pro-13-inch-2010.aspx#axzz19vRNMfSf

http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=35568

Comment: More specs here: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/stats/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-mid-2010-unibody-specs.html

Comment: Which does have VT-x. But make sure that is the right one since the same basic model can have different CPU models. Best to find the exact model number and look on the manufacturers site.